# Markup code parsed unexpectedly

Tags: support, bug

I usually present code by indenting lines with four spaces or using the respective button in the editing menu.

```
line_of = "code"
another = "line"
```

However, after a numbered or bullet list with

1. some item
2. another item

   code_is_formatted = False
   behaviour = "INCONSISTENT"

Just after adding some other item.

```
code_indentation = "works"
```

Is this a bug or am I using the markdown wrong?

Comment: You just need another 4 indents (so a total of 8). There is mention of this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3327/code-block-is-not-properly-formatted-when-placed-immediately-after-a-list-item). Seems that the markdown specification isn't clear as to what should happen in this specific case. For some reason adding another 4 spaces solves this.

Comment: @RayMairlot But then the codeblock is indented as if it were part of the list. What if I want to end the list and add the code block?

Comment: More information [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266890/minor-code-formatting-problem-when-placed-after-a-bulleted-list). You can place an empty line after the bullet point then `<!-->` then another empty line and then code.

Comment: This is a well known problem which would be fixed by the [addition of fenced code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/238438), but there's no information on when or if those are to be implemented.